# How to fix bad URL that conflict with date search?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, url, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a page that showing user's data on a table using bootstrap and php laravel. It have search by date and search by name function, form control per page drop down, page button, and any other button that I think not relevant to the problem.

The problem is when I try to go to page to or change the per page data from 10 to 25, it get error because the link that are provided is wrong.

For example when I try to go to page 2, the link should be :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/master/user?page=2

but instead, the link goes like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/master/user?page=2&start_date=%5Bobject%20HTMLInputElement%5D&end_date=%5Bobject%20HTMLInputElement%5D

and when I change the page data to 25 the link should be like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/master/user?per_page=25

but again it goes like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/master/user?per_page=25&start_date=%5Bobject%20HTMLInputElement%5D&end_date=%5Bobject%20HTMLInputElement%5D

I try to write the link manually instead of pushing buttons and the page show up just fine. So I think the problem is that when I click the button it always give bad link and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the code for the index view

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @include('components.notification')
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="date" id="start_date" class="form-control" value="{{ $_GET['start_date'] ?? '' }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="date" id="end_date" class="form-control" value="{{ $_GET['end_date'] ?? '' }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="search_date()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3 align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <h5>{{ $title }}</h5>
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                <a href="{{ url($default . '/synchronize') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2">Sinkronisasi</a>
                                    @if(!empty($start_date) && !empty($end_date))
                                        <a href="{{ url($default . '/export?type='.$type.'&start_date='. $start_date .'&end_date='.$end_date) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info mr-2">Export</a>
                                    @else
                                        <a href="{{ url($default . '/export?type='.$type) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info mr-2">Export</a>
                                    @endif
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="form-inline justify-content-end">
                            <div class="mr-2">Show per page</div>
                                <div class="mr-2">
                                    <select name="per_page" class="form-control per_page">
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                        <option value="25">25</option>
                                        <option value="50">50</option>
                                        <option value="100">100</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dt-responsive table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="100">No</th>
                                    <th>Nama</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>No HP</th>
                                    <th>No Identitas</th>
                                    <th>Tipe</th>
                                    <th>Nomor Anggota</th>
                                    <th>Kode Referral</th>
                                    <th width="100">Aksi</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @if (count($datas['data']) > 0)
                                    @foreach ($datas['data'] as $data)
                                        @if ($loop->first)
                                            @php
                                                $current = $datas['page'];
                                                $page = ($datas['page'] - 1) * $datas['limit'];
                                                $total_pages = $datas['total_page'];
                                                $count = $page + count($datas['data']);
                                                $no = 1 + $page;
                                            @endphp
                                        @endif
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data['nama'] }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data['email'] }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data['no_hp'] }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data['no_identitas'] }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data['tipe'] }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data['no_cif'] ?? '' }}</td>
                                            @php
                                                $code = '-';
                                                if ($data['code'] !== null || $data['code'] != '') {
                                                    $string = str_split($data['code'], 5);
                                                    $code = implode('-', $string);
                                                }
                                            @endphp
                                        <td>{{ $code }}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="{{ url('master/user/' . $data['_id']) }}" class="mr-3"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                @else
                                    <tr class="text-center">
                                        <td colspan="9">No data available in table</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endif
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div>
                            @if (count($datas['data']) > 0)
                                Showing {{ 1 + $page }} to {{ $count }} of {{ $datas['total_data'] }} entries
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="ml-auto" id="pagination">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var base_url = "{{ url($default) }}"
    var current = parseInt("{{ $current ?? 1 }}")
    var total_pages = parseInt("{{ $total_pages ?? 0 }}")
    var per_page = parseInt("{{ $_GET['per_page'] ?? 10 }}")
    var search = "{{ $_GET['search'] ?? '' }}"
</script>

<script>
    function search_date() {

        if($('#start_date').val() != '' &&  $('#end_date').val() != '' && $('#search').val() != ''){
            start_date = $('#start_date').val()
            end_date = $('#end_date').val()
            search = $('#search').val()
            change_page()
        } else {
            start_date = ''
            end_date = ''
            search = $('#search').val()
            change_page()
        }
    }
</script>

<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/custom-pagination.js') }}"></script>
```

And here is the controller that written using PHP Laravel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Service\SystemService;
use App\Service\MasterService;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    private $folder = 'master/user';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('ceklogin');
        $this->middleware('roleAcces:Superadmin');
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $system = new SystemService();
        $systemData = $system->list_badges();
        $data['system'] = $systemData['data'];

        $api = new MasterService();

        if(!empty($request->start_date) && !empty($request->end_date)){
            $parameter = '';
            if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])){
                $parameter = '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            }
        }else{
            $parameter = '?search='.$request->search;
            if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])){
                $parameter = '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            }
        }

        $data['datas'] = $api->list_users($parameter);
        $data['start_date'] = $request->start_date;
        $data['end_date'] = $request->end_date;
        $data['type'] = 'export';

        $data['title'] = 'Akun User';
        $data['default'] = $this->folder;
        $data['data_view'] = $this->folder . '/index';
        return view('template', $data);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $system = new SystemService();
        $systemData = $system->list_badges();
        $data['system'] = $systemData['data'];

        $api = new MasterService();
        $data['data'] = $api->get_user($id);

        $data['title'] = 'Lihat Akun User';
        $data['default'] = $this->folder;
        $data['data_view'] = $this->folder . '/show';

        return view('template', $data);
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $system = new SystemService();
        $systemData = $system->list_badges();
        $data['system'] = $systemData['data'];

        $api = new MasterService();
        $data['data'] = $api->get_user($id);

        $data['title'] = 'Ubah Akun User';
        $data['default'] = $this->folder;
        $data['data_view'] = $this->folder . '/edit';

        return view('template', $data);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $api = new MasterService();

        $data['nama'] = $request->input('nama');
        $data['email'] = $request->input('email');
        $data['no_hp'] = $request->input('no_hp');
        $data['no_identitas'] = $request->input('no_identitas');
        $data['no_cif'] = $request->input('no_cif');
        $data['tanggal_lahir'] = $request->input('tanggal_lahir');
        $data['tipe'] = $request->input('tipe');

        $result = $api->update_user($id, $data);

        if ($result['message'] == 'Auth failed') {
            Cookie::forget('token');
            return redirect('login')->with('failed', 'Session Expired');
        } else if ($result['status'] == false) {
            return redirect($this->folder . '/' . $id . '/edit')->with('failed', $result['message']);
        } else {
            return redirect($this->folder . '/' . $id)->with('success', $result['message']);
        }
    }

    public function synchronize()
    {
        $api = new MasterService();
        $result = $api->synchronize_users();

        if ($result['message'] == 'Auth failed') {
            Cookie::forget('token');
            return redirect('login')->with('failed', 'Session Expired');
        } else if ($result['status'] == false) {
            return redirect('master/user')->with('failed', $result['message']);
        } else {
            return redirect('master/user')->with('success', $result['message']);
        }
    }

    public function synchronize_member()
    {
        $api = new MasterService();
        $result = $api->synchronize_members();

        if ($result['message'] == 'Auth failed') {
            Cookie::forget('token');
            return redirect('login')->with('failed', 'Session Expired');
        } else if ($result['status'] == false) {
            return redirect('master/user')->with('failed', $result['message']);
        } else {
            return redirect('master/user')->with('success', $result['message']);
        }
    }

    public function export(Request $request)
    {
        $api = new MasterService();
        $parameter = '';
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])){
            $parameter = '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
        $datas = $api->list_users($parameter);


        if ($datas['status'] == true) :
            header('Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report User.xls');
            $export = '
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Tanggal Daftar</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Nama</th>
                        <th>No. HP</th>
                        <th>No Identitas</th>
                        <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
                        <th>No Anggota</th>
                        <th>Alamat</th>
                        <th>Kode Cabang</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
                $no = 1;
                foreach ($datas['data'] as $data) :
                    $export .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td>' . $no++ . '</td>
                        <td>' . $data['tanggal_bergabung']  . '</td>
                        <td>' . $data['email']  . '</td>
                        <td>' . $data['nama']  . '</td>
                        <td>' . $data['no_hp']  . '</td>
                        <td>' . $data['no_identitas']  . '</td>
                        <td>' . $data['tanggal_lahir']  . '</td>
                        <td>' . $data['no_cif']  . '</td>
                        <td>' . $data['alamat']  . '</td>
                        <td>' . $data['kode_cabang']  . '</td>
                        <td>' . $data['tipe']  . '</td>
                    </tr>';
                endforeach;
            $export .= '
                </tbody>
            </table>';

            echo $export;
        endif;
    }

    public function referral($id)
    {
        $system = new SystemService();
        $systemData = $system->list_badges();
        $data['system'] = $systemData['data'];

        $parameter = '';
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $parameter = '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
        $api = new MasterService();
        $data['data'] = $api->get_user($id);
        $data['referral'] = $api->get_user_referral($id, $parameter);
        $data['datas'] = $api->get_user_referral_history($id, $parameter);

        $data['title'] = 'Kode Referral';
        $data['default'] = $this->folder;
        $data['data_view'] = $this->folder . '/referral';
        // return $data;
        return view('template', $data);
    }

    public function emoney($id)
    {
        $system = new SystemService();
        $systemData = $system->list_badges();
        $data['system'] = $systemData['data'];

        $parameter = '';
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $parameter = '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
        $api = new MasterService();
        $data['data'] = $api->get_user($id);
        $data['datas'] = $api->get_user_gv_money($id, $parameter);

        $data['title'] = 'GV Modey';
        $data['default'] = $this->folder;
        $data['data_view'] = $this->folder . '/gv_money';
        // return $data;
        return view('template', $data);
    }

    public function merchant($id)
    {
        $system = new SystemService();
        $systemData = $system->list_badges();
        $data['system'] = $systemData['data'];

        $parameter = '';
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $parameter = '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
        $api = new MasterService();
        $data['data'] = $api->get_user($id);
        $data['datas'] = $api->get_user_gv_merchant($id, $parameter);

        $data['title'] = 'GV Merchant';
        $data['default'] = $this->folder;
        $data['data_view'] = $this->folder . '/gv_merchant';
        // return $data;
        return view('template', $data);
    }

    public function store($id)
    {
        $system = new SystemService();
        $systemData = $system->list_badges();
        $data['system'] = $systemData['data'];

        $parameter = '';
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $parameter = '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
        $api = new MasterService();
        $data['data'] = $api->get_user($id);
        $data['datas'] = $api->get_user_store($id, $parameter);

        $data['title'] = 'User Store';
        $data['default'] = $this->folder;
        $data['data_view'] = $this->folder . '/store';
        // return $data;
        return view('template', $data);
    }

    public function transaction($id)
    {
        $system = new SystemService();
        $systemData = $system->list_badges();
        $data['system'] = $systemData['data'];

        $parameter = '';
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $parameter = '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
        $api = new MasterService();
        $data['data'] = $api->get_user($id);
        $data['datas'] = $api->get_transaksi_user($id, $parameter);

        $data['title'] = 'Transaksi';
        $data['default'] = $this->folder;
        $data['data_view'] = $this->folder . '/transaksi';
        // return $data;
        return view('template', $data);
    }
}
```

I tried deleting the function search date script to see if that's the problem. But the problem still the same. So I don't know which part of the code that I should fix. Can someone please help? Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Can you show the controller? Do you use livewire?

Comment: What does `change_page()` do?

Comment: The issue might be that you're relying on `$_GET` to pass your parameters from one page to another, and then you might be reading the entire URL, `$_GET` and all, when creating your pagination. Going along with what @apokryfos asked - can you post your `change_page()` function as well? Also, a sample of your rendered HTML and JS could help as well.

Comment: Sure.. I've added the controller. I think the problem had something to do with multiple search parameter in one page. I'm not sure about what the change_page( ) does. I think its to reload the page when the condition has been met. Its already been there before I join the project and it seems to be used on other index that has search function in it. I try left click and go to definition but no definition found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved guys. I just try to add some stuff on the script and it works just fine (luckily). Maybe someone can give better explanation why the stuff I add make it work?

```
<script>
var base_url = "{{ url($default) }}"
var current = parseInt("{{ $current ?? 1 }}")
var total_pages = parseInt("{{ $total_pages ?? 0 }}")
var per_page = parseInt("{{ $_GET['per_page'] ?? 10 }}")
var search = "{{ $_GET['search'] ?? '' }}"

var start_date = "{{ $_GET['start_date'] ?? '' }}"
var end_date = "{{ $_GET['end_date'] ?? '' }}"
var type = "{{ $_GET['type'] ?? '' }}"
var url = "{{ url($default) }}"
var page = "{{ $current ?? 1 }}"
var limit = "{{ $datas['limit'] ?? 10 }}"

function search_date() {

    if($('#start_date').val() != '' &&  $('#end_date').val() != '' && $('#search').val() != ''){
        start_date = $('#start_date').val()
        end_date = $('#end_date').val()
        search = $('#search').val()
        change_page()
    } else {
        start_date = ''
        end_date = ''
        search = $('#search').val()
        change_page()
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).